# Code for counting no. of 0s and 1s in binary representation of a letter

Tags: c, loops, if-statement

Basically, I have to write a code such that:

1. a letter is taken as an input.
2. no. of 0s and 1s in the binary representation of it's ascii value are counted
3. report (no. of 0s)*(no. of 1s)

Please help me find mistakes in my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    
    int x,y,count0,count1,a,r;
        scanf("%c",&x);
        a = (int)x;

        count0 = 0;
        count1 = 0;
        while(a != 0){
            r=a%2;
            if(r == 0) 
                count0 = count0 + 1;
            else if(r == 1) 
                count1 = count1 + 1;
            a = a/2;
        }
        y = count1 * count0;
        printf("%d\n",count0);
        printf("%d\n",count1);
        printf("%d",y);
        return 0;
}
```

Clearly this is wrong as for the input 'A', it should print 5,2,10 but it is giving out 16,7,112.

Comment: "for the input 'A', it should print 5,2,10" - "6, 2, 12," surely? Or are you using 7-bit ascii values?

Comment: @SRNissen i am using decimal ASCII table

Comment: What is wrong with shifting a mask?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you declared x as int, `scanf("%c",&x);` produces:

> test.c:5:17: warning: format ‘%c’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int *’ [-Wformat=]

Also default char is signed, which may produce surprising numbers of ones and zeroes if you encounter one of the negative values.

Change the type of x to be `unsigned char`:

```
unsigned char x;
int y,count0,count1,a,r;
```

then the code should do what you wanted.

If you don't have warnings enabled in your compiler, enable them now. They are usually helpful in detecting problems like this.

Answer (score 3):

I remember an old trick from K&R; c &= c - 1 clears the lowest 1-bit in c.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
    {
    int ones, zeros;
    unsigned char c;
    
    scanf("%c", &c);
    for (ones = 0; c; ++ones)
        c &= c - 1;
    zeros = CHAR_BIT - ones;
    printf("zeros: %d\n", zeros);
    printf("ones: %d\n", ones);
    printf("product: %d\n", ones * zeros);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues:

1. As teapot418 said in the other answer, you have to read your character into an unsigned char
2. You stop counting as soon as `a == 0`, meaning you will only count `1`'s and `0`'s until the most significant `1`. Conside the space character, its value is `32` or `00100000`. Your code will count 5 `0`'s and 1 `1`. To fix that, only count the `1`s and then calculate the number of `0`s from that by `count0 = 8 - count1` (or `7 - count1` for 7bit ascii)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @SRNissen that the proper answer is `6,2,12` because `'A'` in binary is `0100 0001`.

My code to do this with masking is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main(){
    unsigned char x = 'A';

    int count0 = 0;
    int count1 = 0;
    for( int i=0; i<CHAR_BIT; ++i)
    {
        count0 += !(x & 1<<i);
        count1 += !!(x & 1<<i);
    }

    int y = count1 * count0;
    
    printf("%d\n",count0);
    printf("%d\n",count1);
    printf("%d",y);
    return 0;
}
```